While Migrating from java client SDK2 to SDK 3, how can i implement RetryStrategy
I am migrating from couchbase java client SDK 2 to SDK3.
in SDK2 code I have a method which is calling upsert method on AsyncBucket with retry mechanism.
below is the code [SDK2]
client.getBucket().async().upsert(doc).retryWhen(getRetryFunction());  // client.getBucket() return object of Bucket
The above mentioned code snippet defines a retry mechanism for handling specific Couchbase exceptions using the RetryBuilder class. This mechanism is part of the getRetryFunction method
getRetryFunction()  is implemented like below
public RetryWhenFunction getRetryFunction()
    {

       return RetryBuilder.anyOf(TemporaryFailureException.class, TemporaryLockFailureException.class, BackpressureException.class, ReplicaNotAvailableException.class, RequestCancelledException.class, CouchbaseOutOfMemoryException.class)
      .delay(((CouchbaseRetryStrategy) retryStrategy)
      .determineRetryStrategy())
      .max(retryStrategy.getMaxAttempts())
      .build();
    }

// ((CouchbaseRetryStrategy) retryStrategy).determineRetryStrategy(),  it returns object of Delay
This code sets up a retry mechanism that will attempt to retry operations when specific Couchbase exceptions occur, using a defined delay strategy and a maximum number of attempts.
Now I am migerating to SDK3 so I want similar behaviour as above code.
I am not able to find the retry mechanism in SDK3.
my expectation is to write a code which will be behaving same.

One of the major changes in Couchbase SDK3 was that the SDK now retries automatically when it is safe to do so.
We do provide a RetryStrategy interface for users that want to customise the behaviour, and please see this link for details on that.
But almost all users are satisfied with the SDK out-of-the-box retry behaviour, which is implemented in the BestEffortRetryStrategy.
